# Long-running cell in Vscode Jupyter: Reconnecting to the kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Whenever I run a Jupyter cell in Vscode that takes a long time to complete, it does not ever seem to complete running the cell.

At the bottom of Vscode, I will see the notification

> Reconnecting to the kernel myvenv (Python 3.8.16)

Is it possible that this issue is due to the cell taking longer than a configurable amout of time to complete running? If so, is there a way to increase this timeout value?

There is no problem when the cell completes running in ~5mins.

Pip packages: `jupyter_client==7.4.8`, `jupyter_core==5.1.1`, `jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.5`.

Vscode extension `Jupyter` is on `v2023.2.1000541047`

Comment: Possibly related: [Reconnecting to the kernel Python 3.8](/q/75517090/11107541) and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12775

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar issues on GitHub about this issue. Please try to uninstall and install the latest version of **jupyter** package. Also use `pip install --upgrade ipykernel` to upgrade *ipykernel*.

Regarding the time limit you said, the setting below is an option.

[image]